# In Python/RobotFramework How Should I Append the required keys, values from nested json into another file?

Tags: python, json, list, append, robotframework

I have a nested JSON in the below format from where i need to get tags name and values and append if duplicates present into a another json file.

```
${resp}= {
"data": {
"resources": {
"edges": [
{
"node": {
    "tags": [],
   }
},
{          
  "node": {
   "tags": [
      {
        "name": "app",
        "value": "e2e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cost",
         "value": "qwerty"
      }
  }
},
{          
  "node": {
   "tags": [
      {
        "name": "app",
        "value": "e2e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cost",
         "value": "qwerty"
      },
        {
        "name": "test",
         "value": "qwerty"
      }
  }
}
]
}
}
}
```

I need to get the tags keys and values alone and append it and store in a json file. See below the Python code I have tried,.

Python code:

```
def appendjsondata(fileName,data):
 new = {}
 print (data)
 print('forloop before')
 for k,v in data.items():

    print(f'{k}: {v}')
    new["key"] = k
    new["tags"] = []
    new["value"] = v

    #new["tags"].append([{ 'key': k, 'values': v } for k, v in data.items()])
    new["tags"].append(new)
 print(new["tags"])
 with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
   json.dump(new["tags"], f, indent=3 * ' ')  

 return  new["tags"]
```

Robot FRamework Code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   pythonfile.py
Library   JSONLibrary
Library   Collections

*** Test Cases ***
${dict1}=        Set Variable  ${resp}
${cnt}=     get length     ${dict1['data']['resources']['edges']}
${edge}=   set variable      ${dict1['data']['resources']['edges']}

run keyword if   ${cnt}==0     set test message    The resources count is Zero(0)
log to console  ${cnt}-count

: FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE   0    ${cnt}
\    ${readName}=    Set Variable     ${edge[${item}]['node']['configuration']}
\    ${tag_Count}=    get length     ${edge[${item}]['node']['tags']}
\    ${tag_variable}=   set variable   ${edge[${item}]['node']['tags']}
\    forkeyword       ${tag_Count}   ${tag_variable}    ${readName}

 ${req_json}    Json.Dumps    ${dict}
 Create File  results.json  ${req_json}


forkeyword
[Arguments]       ${tag_Count}      ${tag_variable}     ${readName}
@{z}=   create list
: FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE   0    ${tag_Count}
         \   ${resourceName}=    run keyword if     ${tag_Count} > 0   set variable    ${readName['name']}
         \   log to console  ${resourceName}-forloop
         \   ${readkey}=     set variable   ${tag_variable[${item}]['name']}
         \   ${readvalue}=     set variable   ${tag_variable[${item}]['value']}
         \   set to dictionary     ${dict}     resourceName   ${resourceName}
         \   set to dictionary  ${dict}    ${readkey}     ${readvalue}
         \    appendjsondata      results.json    ${dict}
set suite variable ${dict}
```

ERROR:

No keyword appendjsondata found

Comment: Please paste the `*** Settings ***` part of the Robot code and describe the relative location of the Python script. Also, based on the sample, it seems that the Python script is not indented correctly (the rows below function definition). Check first that the Python script works, and then import it and use in RF.

Comment: Added settings, And I have checked the python code is running successfully at standalone execution.
I also need help on how to fetch the key values and store it in a json file

Comment: Also the JSON is invalid, please correct it. Preferably run it through a JSON validator to make sure it's valid before pasting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one space in the Library import. Use two or more spaces in the import, e.g.,
`Library    pythonfile.py`.

And check that the `pythonfile.py` is in the same directory as the RF file.

Answer (score 1):

Robot file is not recognizing keyword defined in python program. check below steps:

1.Check python program is not having compilation issue and is imported correctly. Console will show error message.

2. Add  ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE' in your python class definition.

Comment: Why step number 2? The Python script does not need to know anything about Robot.

Comment: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html , Search for ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE  in the link.Its documentation linl.  It provides details of scope of keywords. It might help you.

Comment: I believe the Python script in this case is not a) a class, and b) it does not have internal state. So why add ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE. Which problem will it resolve?

Comment: I generally create Python keywords setup as class and import it to Robot. Not sure direct usage as block of python module.